# Dificuldade em dinamizar colunas no MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Senhores, bom dia !

Estou tendo um pouco de dificuldade para construir essa consulta no Microsoft SQL 2019

Alguém poderia talvez me dar uma luz ?

Tenho uma base assim

Codfuncionario | cod_centro_custo | perc_rateio

```
 1         |       1          |    50%
 1         |       2          |    50%
 2         |       1          |    100%
```

E preciso transformá-la na seguinte forma dinamicamente:

codFuncionario | cod_centro_custo_1 | perc_valor1 | cod_centro_custo2 | perc_valor2 ..

```
 1         |        1           |    50%      |       2           |    50%
 2         |        1           |    100%     |     NULL          |    NULL
```

Comment: e o que já tenou fazer? coloque na pergunta sua query atual e onde está com dificuldade

Comment: Pesquise por PIVOT , https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava indo para o caminho de fazer pivot, mas não é necessariamente o que preciso, porque quero que os campos do centro de custo que estão nas colunas fiquem em linhas.

Eu estava usando essa consulta, mas ela gera somente o cabecalho com o texto do centro de custo desta forma

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

declare
@colunas_pivot as nvarchar(max)
,@comando_sql  as nvarchar(max)

SET @colunas_pivot =
stuff((
SELECT
DISTINCT ',' + quotename(CODCENCUS) --, ',' + quotename('valor')
FROM TFPRTF
FOR XML PATH ('')
), 1, 1, '')
print @colunas_pivot
set @comando_sql = '
select * from (
SELECT
CODFUNC
,CODCENCUS
,SUM(PERCRATEIO) AS PERCRATEIO
FROM TFPRTF
GROUP BY
CODFUNC
,CODCENCUS
) em_linha
pivot ( sum(PERCRATEIO) for CODCENCUS in (' + @colunas_pivot + ')) em_colunas
order by 1'
print @comando_sql
execute(@comando_sql)
go

E preciso que fique assim :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O ponto ruim do pivot é que o que será 'colunado' precisa ser conhecido e nomeado , mas me parece ser caso de pivot sim. As vezes (Oracle) faço o PIVOT por CASE , pode ser o caso , mas também cai no problemas das colunas terem de serem conhecidas.